# Subscribe to all storage

Tags: polkadot-js

Reading through this: https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.multi/
It states "It should be trivially extendable to subscribe to the validators, track which one have entered or left". How is this possible? I thought that something like this would work but it doesn't

`api.query.staking.validators.multi((validators) => {console.log(validators)});`

Answer (score 0):

You can subscribe without `multi` as well. For example:

```js
await api.query.system.events(events =>
    events.forEach(({event}) => console.log(event.toHuman())))
```

- https://polkadot.js.org/docs/api/start/api.query.subs#subscriptions

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```js
await api.query.session.validators(validators => 
    console.table(validators.map(validator => validator.toHuman())))
```